# How to show specific data on modal without unique value (id) in php

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I have a data set coming from an `API`. Data does not have an id attribute in it. When we want to show specific data on the base of its id in modal we declare a `data-id` attribute in `html` but if we do not have any `id` associated to data. How can we show the contents of it on modal?

See the data, I am showing `name` and have `more-info` button for `modal`. what should i do, when someone clicks on `more-info` button. It shows specific content?

There is also a next url in the data how can i paginate it in php?

```
{
"count": 37, 
"next": "http://some-url/api/stars/?page=2", 
"previous": null, 
"results": [
    {
        "name": "Sentinel-class landing craft", 
        "model": "Sentinel-class landing craft", 
        "manufacturer": "Sienar Fleet Systems, Cyngus Spaceworks", 
        "cost_in_credits": "240000", 
        "length": "38", 
        "max_atmosphering_speed": "1000", 
        "crew": "5", 
        "passengers": "75", 
        "cargo_capacity": "180000", 
        "consumables": "1 month", 
        "hyperdrive_rating": "1.0", 
        "MGLT": "70", 
        "starship_class": "landing craft", 
        "pilots": [], 
        "films": [
            "http://some-url/api/films/1/"
        ], 
        "created": "2014-12-10T15:48:00.586000Z", 
        "edited": "2014-12-22T17:35:44.431407Z", 
        "url": "http://some-url/api/stars/5/"
    }, 
    {
        "name": "Death Star", 
        "model": "DS-1 Orbital Battle Station", 
        "manufacturer": "Imperial Department of Military Research, Sienar Fleet Systems", 
        "cost_in_credits": "1000000000000", 
        "length": "120000", 
        "max_atmosphering_speed": "n/a", 
        "crew": "342953", 
        "passengers": "843342", 
        "cargo_capacity": "1000000000000", 
        "consumables": "3 years", 
        "hyperdrive_rating": "4.0", 
        "MGLT": "10", 
        "starship_class": "Deep Space Mobile Battlestation", 
        "pilots": [], 
        "films": [
            "http://some-url.co/api/films/1/"
        ], 
        "created": "2014-12-10T16:36:50.509000Z", 
        "edited": "2014-12-22T17:35:44.452589Z", 
        "url": "http://some-url.co/api/starships/9/"
    },
```

Comment: how do you get this data?, based on what?,how do you index your data for querying?

Comment: actually i am getting this data from an `API` data comes in the form of `JSON`

Comment: your db seems to have a unique key associated with the particular values from what i see in the urls ,why isn't returned from the service provider as well?

Comment: i dont know i am also confused on this point.

Comment: Could you please tell me, how can i paginate data using its `next` and `previous link` @madalinivascu I know its basic but i am confused a little.

Comment: you can do this based on the keys of the results array, if your data doesn't change you may need to store the data in a more permanent environment like a database where you would add a unique id to each value

Comment: what is count here?? the total pages count .??

Comment: Total pages are `4`. I am unable to understand how can i make the show the details when clicked on a button link of `?page= 3;`

Answer (score 0):

```
$arrayData = json_decode($jsonData);
$i=0;
foreach($arrayData->results as $data)
{   
    $arrayData->results[$i]->name;
    $arrayData->results[$i]->id=$i;
    $i++;
}
```